# I couldn't find the tag amiga-os, what tag should be used for questions about AmigaOS?

Tags: support, retag-request

Shouldn't AmigaOS has its own tag?
Or what tag should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say no.

Tags are intended as a multi dimensional system. If we define special tag for each and every OS and each and every component thereof, the system of tags turns into a single dimensional set categories, removing any synergy in searching - beside being bloated as hell.